# JSF Method not Found Exception

Tags: jsf

I'm working on learning some web development I have mostly only worked purely in Java or C++ in the past.

I'm trying to create a little web based Yahtzee game and having some trouble starting out.

I'm getting a method not found exception when trying to use a command button to call a function.

I tried calling this function with just 0 as well and the same thing occurred:

*The stack trace*

```
javax.faces.el.MethodNotFoundException: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,97 action="#{dice.shouldHold(varStatus.index)}": Method shouldHold not found
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.broadcast(UIRepeat.java:1045)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,97 action="#{dice.shouldHold(varStatus.index)}": Method shouldHold not found
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 37 more
```

xhtml code:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Roll" action="#{dice.roll()}" ></h:commandButton>
            <br/><br/>
            <ui:repeat var="dice" value="#{dice.dice}" varStatus="varStatus"> 
                <h:commandButton value="#{dice}" action="#{dice.shouldHold(varStatus.index)}" /> 
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

java code:
     dice.java:
    package components;

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author Dave
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Dice 
{
    private Die dice[];
    private String diceString;

    public Dice()
    {
        dice = new Die[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
            dice[i] = new Die();
        diceString = "";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void reset()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
            dice[i].reset();

        diceString = "";

    }

    public Die[] getDice()  {   return dice;    }
    public String getDiceString()   {   return diceString;  }

    public void setDice(Die dice[]) {   this.dice = dice;   }
    public void setDiceString (String diceString)   {   this.diceString = diceString;   }

    public void roll()
    {
        reset();

        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
            if(!dice[i].getHold())
                dice[i].roll();
    }


    public void shouldHold(int index)
    {
        if(!dice[index].getHold())
            dice[index].setHold(true);
        else
            dice[index].setHold(false);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
            diceString = dice.toString() + " ";

        return diceString;
    }
}

 die.java:
package components;


import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Die 
{
    final private int MINIMUM = 1;
    final private int MAXIMUM = 6;

    private int face;
    private String faceString;
    private boolean hold;

    public Die()
    {
        reset();
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        face = 0;
        faceString = "";
        hold = false;
    }

    public int getFace()    {   return face;    }
    public String getFaceString()   {return faceString; }
    public boolean getHold()    {   return hold;    }

    public void setFace(int face)   {   this.face = face;   }
    public void setFaceString(String faceString)    {   this.faceString = faceString;    }
    public void setHold(boolean hold)   {   this.hold = hold;   }

    public void roll()
    {
        int randomNum = 0;

        randomNum = MINIMUM + (int)(Math.random() * MAXIMUM);
        face = randomNum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return faceString = face + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Who voted to close due to missing code? The code seems to be there since the initial post!!!

Comment: That's strange... Tried your code and it invokes `shouldHold` method.

Comment: Then most likely the code you are running is not the code you think you are running. Do some cleaning and a fully new deploy